# Aligning chemical equations in a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, mhchem

I have a table containing some chemical equations, some with more than one line. Can I align all of them at their reaction arrows without some much space around it? Dividing the reactions into parts is my best solution so far:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrreprt}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    \usepackage[a4paper,left=35mm,right=20mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{tabulary} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LrclR}
    corrosion product & \multicolumn{3}{c}{degradation process} & max. T\textcelsius\\
    \toprule
    Malachite & \ce{CuCO3.CH(OH)2} & \ce{->T[380\textcelsius]} & \ce{2CuO + H2O + CO2} & 380\\
    \addlinespace
    Azurite & \ce{2CuCO3.Cu(OH)2} & \ce{->T[320--355\textcelsius]} & \ce{CuCO3.Cu(OH)2 + CuO + CO2 + H2O} & 390\\
            & \ce{CuCO3.Cu(OH)2} & \ce{->T[390\textcelsius]} & \ce{CuO + O2 + H2O} & \\ 
    \addlinespace
    Atacamite & \ce{CU(OH)3Cl} & \ce{->T[250\textcelsius]} & \ce{CuO.CuCl2 + CuO +H2O} & 400\\
            & \ce{CuO.CuCl2 + 1/2 O2} & \ce{->T[400\textcelsius]} & \ce{2CuO + Cl2} & \\
    \bottomrule
   \end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

But it looks rather ragged. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get equal length central arrows by deciding which one is the widest:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[a4paper,left=35mm,right=20mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newlength{\cewidth}
\newcommand{\cet}[1]{\makebox[\cewidth]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\cewidth}{\scriptsize 320--355\textcelsius}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l r@{}c@{}l r@{}}
\toprule
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} Corrosion \\ product \end{tabular} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Degradation process} &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} Max.\\ T\textcelsius \end{tabular} \\
\midrule
Malachite
  & \ce{CuCO3.CH(OH)2} & \ce{->T[\cet{380\textcelsius}]} & \ce{2CuO + H2O + CO2} & 380\\
\addlinespace
Azurite
  & \ce{2CuCO3.Cu(OH)2} & \ce{->T[320--355\textcelsius]} & \ce{CuCO3.Cu(OH)2 + CuO + CO2 + H2O}
    & 390\\
  & \ce{CuCO3.Cu(OH)2} & \ce{->T[\cet{390\textcelsius}]} & \ce{ CuO + O2 + H2O} & \\ 
\addlinespace
Atacamite
  & \ce{CU(OH)3Cl} & \ce{->T[\cet{250\textcelsius}]} & \ce{CuO.CuCl2 + CuO +H2O} & 400\\
  & \ce{CuO.CuCl2 + 1/2 O2} & \ce{->T[\cet{400\textcelsius}]} & \ce{ 2CuO + Cl2} & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With another trick you can center the header above the arrows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[a4paper,left=35mm,right=20mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newlength{\cewidth}
\newcommand{\cet}[1]{\makebox[\cewidth]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\cewidth}{\scriptsize 320--355\textcelsius}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l r@{}c@{}l r@{}}
\toprule
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} Corrosion \\ product \end{tabular} &
  & \makebox[0pt]{Degradation process} & &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} Max.\\ T\textcelsius \end{tabular} \\
\midrule
Malachite
  & \ce{CuCO3.CH(OH)2} & \ce{->T[\cet{380\textcelsius}]} & \ce{2CuO + H2O + CO2} & 380\\
\addlinespace
Azurite
  & \ce{2CuCO3.Cu(OH)2} & \ce{->T[320--355\textcelsius]} & \ce{CuCO3.Cu(OH)2 + CuO + CO2 + H2O}
    & 390\\
  & \ce{CuCO3.Cu(OH)2} & \ce{->T[\cet{390\textcelsius}]} & \ce{ CuO + O2 + H2O} & \\ 
\addlinespace
Atacamite
  & \ce{CU(OH)3Cl} & \ce{->T[\cet{250\textcelsius}]} & \ce{CuO.CuCl2 + CuO +H2O} & 400\\
  & \ce{CuO.CuCl2 + 1/2 O2} & \ce{->T[\cet{400\textcelsius}]} & \ce{ 2CuO + Cl2} & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I insert the text in the column with the arrows, but inside `\makebox[0pt]{...}` which makes the text occupy no width (from the point of view of TeX) and stick on either side of this zero width box. Of course this can work only because the neighboring columns are wide enough.

[image]

Comment: That's definitely an improvement while including Micos solution, also with the alignment towards the arrows. Does the position of the middle table head look odd, when not aligned as well? Not really part of the question, just wondering.

Comment: @fortunecookies You can center “Degradation process” above the arrows by changing `\multicolumn{3}{c}{Degradation process}` into `&\makebox[0pt]{Degradation process}&`

Comment: Looks again much better. How does this work? How does \makebox expand one single cell?

Comment: @fortunecookies I make the text to occupy no width; of course this works well because there is enough room in the neighboring columns.

Comment: sounds freaking ingeniously :D

Answer (score 2):

You might try eliminating the whitespace that LaTeX inserts by default between columns -- at least around the three central columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[left=35mm, right=20mm, vmargin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{textcomp,booktabs,tabulary} 

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{} L l@{}c@{}l R @{}}
Corrosion product 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Degradation process} 
& Max.\ T\textcelsius\\
\toprule
Malachite & \ce{CuCO3.CH(OH)2} 
          & \ce{->T[380\textcelsius]} 
          & \ce{2CuO + H2O + CO2} & 380\\
\addlinespace
Azurite   & \ce{2CuCO3.Cu(OH)2} 
          & \ce{->T[320--355\textcelsius]} 
          & \ce{CuCO3.Cu(OH)2 + CuO + CO2 + H2O} & 390\\
          & \ce{CuCO3.Cu(OH)2} 
          & \ce{->T[390\textcelsius]} 
          & \ce{CuO + O2 + H2O} & \\ 
\addlinespace
Atacamite & \ce{CU(OH)3Cl} 
          & \ce{->T[250\textcelsius]} 
          & \ce{CuO.CuCl2 + CuO +H2O} & 400\\
          & \ce{CuO.CuCl2 + 1/2 O2} 
          & \ce{->T[400\textcelsius]}
          & \ce{2CuO + Cl2} & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's better indeed but if there was a solution that keeps me from hacking the equations into pieces then I'd prefer that.

Comment: @fortunecookies - I'm afraid I don't know much about chemistry and chemical equations. Could you may edit your posting and write out how you would *like* to see the equations displayed?'

Comment: That was already a problem when I posted the question, I don't know how to visualize it. Basically I want to achieve the look of the align-environment without the numbered lines and inside the table. I tried to simply include it in the table, but it did not work - obviously.